# Sort array list with two date objects in android

Tags: android, listview, comparator

I have a ArrayList with custom objects. Each object has two date entities `Call date` and `Appointment date`. This information (along with others) are displayed in a list view and everything so far is working fine.

The `Call date` is never null and is always valid date from the server. However, the `Appointment date` can be null for a few entries. The date format for both `Call date` and `Appointment date` is the same `(Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970)`

The sorting should work like this:

- The `Call date` should be sorted in Descending order of date
- Appointment date, if not null should show on top. However, it has to be sorted in the ascending order of the date (e.g.: If there are two appointments one on 19th August and the other on 21st August, the 19th August should show on top and the 21st below it) and all nulls should be at the bottom

Currently, I have got the `Call date` and `Appointment date` sorted by using two separate comparators. However, the `Appointment date` is in descending order instead of the ascending order (21st is showing on top, 19th below it and nulls at the end) as required.

The comparator code is below

```
    public class CallDateComparator implements Comparator< ListModel > {
        @Override
        public int compare(ListModel o1, ListModel o2) {
            if (o2.getCallDate() != null && o1. getCallDate() != null)
                return o2.getProspectDate().compareTo(o1.getProspectDate());
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public class AppointmentDateComparator implements Comparator< ListModel > {
        @Override
        public int compare(ListModel o1, ListModel o2) {
            if (o2.getAppointmentDate() != null && o1.getAppointmentDate() != null)
                return o2.getAppointmentDate().compareTo(o1.getAppointmentDate());
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

I sort the `ArrayList` by calling

```
Collections.sort(myList, new CallDateComparator());
Collections.sort(myList, new AppointmentDateComparator());
```

What needs to be changed above to get the appointment date sorted in ascending order and if it is null, just leave the earlier sorting intact?

Comment: so, what you want to achieve is a list in the next format:  Note X, Call date 20 december, Appointment date 15 jaunuary  Note X, Call date 20 december, Appointment date 16 january  Note X, call date 25 december, Appointment date 5 july  Note X, Call date 25 december, Appointment date  none  right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am after

Comment: return o1.getAppointmentDate().compareTo(o2.getAppointmentDate());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my approach based on the format on the comments :

basically i'd do a bigger comparator rather than two different ones.

```
 public class CallDateComparator implements Comparator< ListModel > {
        @Override
        public int compare(ListModel o1, ListModel o2) {
            if (o2.getCallDate() != null && o1. getCallDate() != null)
                int i = o1.getProspectDate().compareTo(o2.getProspectDate();
                switch (i)
                  case -1: //o1 smaller than o2
                      return -1;
                    break;//this might be not necessary at all.
                  case 0: //both equal, so, same call date.
                        if(o1.getAppointmentDate() != null && o2.getAppointmentDate() == null)
                        {
                          return 1; // make o1 the bigger one.
                        }
                        else if(o1.getAppointmentDate() == null && o2.getAppointmentDate() != null)
                        {
                          return -1; // make o2 the bigger one.
                        }
                        else if(o1.getAppointmentDate() == null && o2.getAppointmentDate() == null)
                        {
                           return 0; //both are equally null.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return o1.getAppointmentDate().compareTo(o2.getAppointmentDate()); //compare then
                        }

                    break;
                  case 1: //o1 bigger than o2
                      return 1;
                    break;//this might be not necessary at all.
                  default:
                      return 0;
                    break;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: made it on notepad, code format is for sure not 100% correct.